# Gradient of a line

Tags: geometry

I have the question "A(1,3), B(5,7),C(4,8),D(a,b) form a rectangle ABCD. Find a and b."

I have worked out the gradient of AB which is 1 and the gradient of CD which is 2 b/a, however , when I checked the solutions b = 4 and a = 0 and I do not understand how this was achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$CD$ must have the same gradient as $AB$.

For $CD$ we have a gradient of

$$\frac{b-8}{a-4}=1$$

which is not the same as what you have.  Instead, this gives us that $a-4=b-8$, so $a=b-4$.

At the same time, $AD$ must have the same gradient as $BC$, so

$$\frac{b-3}{a-1}=-1$$

Which gives $b-3=1-a$, so $a=4-b$.

So we have $4-b=b-4$, which gives $b=4$, and then plugging it back in to either equation we get $a=0$.

Answer (score 1):

it must be $$[4-a,8-b]\cdot [-1,1]=0$$ and $$\sqrt{(4-a)^2+(8-b)^2}=\sqrt{32}$$
can you proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Continuing after your first step, for $CD,AB$ opposite sides have equal slope =

$$\frac{b-8}{a-4}=1$$

in which step you made a mistake.

For $ BC,AD $ slope of opposite sides

$$\frac{b-3}{a-1}=-1$$

the lines are perpendicular , so they must be negative reciprocal of each other. That tallies.

These two equations  solve to $(a,b)= (0,4)$